# Does NVIDIA Optimus technology switches back to the integrated graphics when I ALT+TAB from my game into windows?

Tags: optimus

If I ALT+TAB from my game into windows, does NVidia Optimus switches to the Intel GPU? How can I know which GPU is being used?

Comment: It shouldn't.,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the nVidia Control Panel, select 'Desktop' from the main menu, then check 'Show notification tray icon'. When hovering your cursor over the new icon, or by left-clicking, a notification will appear top left of your screen telling you how many apps are using the nVidia GPU.

Depending on how you have your system configured, the default behaviour would seem to run your game on the nVidia GPU, but the desktop on integrated graphics.